# How to destructure and reassign in one line using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an object `adData` and I need to extract some of it's properties, add some more properties to the extracted object and pass the object as parameter. I can do this using:

```
const params = {}; 
params.id = adData.id;  
params.status = adData.status; 
params.frequency = adData.frequency; 
params.user = getLoggedInUser(); 
callAnotherFunction(params)
```

Can I do the destructing and reassigning to new object in one line ? Something like:

```
const params = {id, status, frequency} = adData; 
params.user = getLoggedInUser();
```

Or

```
const params = {id, status, frequency, getLoggedInUser(): user} = adData;
```

Now these both above syntaxes are wrong but is there any other way to do it using destructuring and without extracting the properties one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what properties the object *does* have, and there aren't that many, you can list them and use rest syntax to gather the others into an object:

```
const { unwantedProp, ...params) = adData;
// use params
```

Otherwise, there isn't any *incredibly simple* syntax for what you want, though you could

```
const params = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(adData).filter(([key]) => 
    ['id', 'status', 'frequency'].includes(key)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do in one line with destructuring and arrow function.

```js
const getLoggedInUser = () => "foo";
const adData = {
  id: 123,
  status: "active",
  frequency: "less",
  bar: 4,
};

const params = (({ id, status, frequency }, user = getLoggedInUser()) => ({
  id,
  status,
  frequency,
  user,
}))(adData);

console.log({ params });
```